# Where is Subrahmanya Sahasranamam mentioned in the Skanda Purana?

Tags: identification-request, skanda-purana, kartikeya

I am unable to find the exact portion in the Skanda purANa where Brahma composes the Sahasranamam for Lord Subrahmanya- It says Eswara Proktam in the Skanda Purana, but I cant find it in the Skanda Purana- Can someone help me?

Comment: At present only a part of the Skanda Purana is available. There could be manuscripts at different places which could shed light on the total or near total text.

Comment: I have been able to find [this version](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_subrahmanya/subra1000naama.itx) of a sahasranama, which finishes with: "iti shrIskAnde mahApurANe Ishvaraprokte brahmanAradasaMvAde". I'm not sure where I can find this in the purAna, but hopefully it is some help.